# Error When analyzing cpp projects with Sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube, linkageerror

I got the below Error when i analyzed a CPP project. i analysed the project with sonar 3.1 and 3.4. But i got the same error
in both the sonar versions. please help me to find and solve the issue..

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar-plugins:maven-cpp-plugin:0.4:metrics (default-cli
) on project ConnectJet: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.sonar-plugins:maven-cpp-plugin:
0.4:metrics failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing      
org.codehaus.sonar-plugins:maven-cpp-plugin:0.4:metrics: java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.0 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader,   
but this RI (from jar:file:/C:/Users/Renjith.R/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/j
axb-impl/2.1.12/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model   
/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.1
API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap   
classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/)
```

Thanks in Advance
Renjith.R

Comment: Did you follow the instruction in the error message - to place `jaxb-api.jar` in the `endorsed` directory and retry?

Comment: yes. there is no directory named `endorsed` in my `<java-home>/jre/lib`. i created `endorsed` directory and put the `jax-api.jar` in it. Now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the comment as an answer since it worked...

The problem is likely due to conflicting version of the `jaxb` API provided by java and required by sonar.

Place 'jaxb-api.jar`in the`endorsed` directory as instructex in the error message.